# Сравнение в словаре

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть словарь. Не могу понять, как можно сравнить значения в словаре и вывести, наибольшее ключ-значения.

```
name_reiteng = {'TanyaZabrodo': 8.76, 'SanyaGypkin': 5.48, 'AnyaSymkina': 10.0, 'AntonDavidov': 4.32, 'VanyaPypkin': 6.96, 'SergeyMolodchikov': 6.76}
```

В данном случае должно вывести: AnyaSymkina: 10.0

в цикле пытался перебрать:(Как сейчас думаю на данный момент, создается переменная в цикле которая сравнивает значение v на данной итерации и если оно больше то записывается новое значение в переменную, но мне нужно чтоб вывод был с ключём, как правильно реализовать?)Вопрос в роде бы и пустяковый, я вот сижу уже минут 30 и не могу понять. Спасибо.

```
for k,v in name_reiteng.items():
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [101]: name_rating
Out[101]:
{'AntonDavidov': 4.32,
 'AnyaSymkina': 10.0,
 'SanyaGypkin': 5.48,
 'SergeyMolodchikov': 6.76,
 'TanyaZabrodo': 8.76,
 'VanyaPypkin': 6.96}

In [102]: from operator import itemgetter

In [103]: champ = sorted(name_rating, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[0]

In [104]: champ
Out[104]: 'AnyaSymkina'

In [105]: name_rating[champ]
Out[105]: 10.0
```

Или гораздо более элегантное решение от [@insolor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/632716/%d0%a1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b5/632720#comment890838_632720):

```
champ = max(name_rating, key=itemgetter(1))
```

Comment: Можно просто `champ = max(name_rating, key=itemgetter(1))`, выполняется за линейное время, в отличие от `sort`.

Comment: @insolor, да, так элегантнее получается, спасибо!